# Set custom timezone in Django/PostgreSQL (Indian Standard Time)

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone, postgresql-9.1

In Django [documentation for setting timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone), the [list of available choices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE) for timezone are actually postgres timezone parameter strings. So it seems Django uses Postgres for retrieving time.

If so, then the problem is that IST is used to denote both [Indian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) & [Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Standard_Time) Standard Time, but postgres uses [IST](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=IST) for Israel Standard Time (potentially confusing over a 6th of world's population) and there is NO timezone string for Indian Standard Time.

Not just that, Postgres also misses timezone for some other countries like Nepal (GMT+5:30) and some Pacific Islands.

So, is there any way by which I can set custom timezone string (like GMT+5:30 for India, GMT+5:45 for Nepal, etc.) in Postgres or Django?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For India:

```
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta';
SELECT now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata';
SELECT now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE '5:30';
```

For Nepal:

```
SELECT now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Katmandu';
SELECT now()::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'NPT';
```

To set the time zone for the whole session:

```
SET time zone 'Asia/Calcutta';
```

To reset it (to the time zone set in postgresql.conf:

```
RESET time zone;
```

Find more in the system views `pg_timezone_names` and `pg_timezone_abbrevs`

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_timezone_names
WHERE  utc_offset BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '06:00:00'
ORDER  BY utc_offset;

SELECT *
FROM   pg_timezone_abbrevs
WHERE  utc_offset BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '06:00:00'
ORDER  BY utc_offset;
```

PostgreSQL manual about [`AT TIME ZONE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct. About [time zones](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES).

Comment: I see, the name of the city was changed from `Calcutta` to `Kolkata` back in 2001. But postgres seems to be in no mood to keep up with changes.
That worked by the way. Thanks!

Comment: @user1144616: Cool that it works. You may have missed the `Asia/Kolkata` in my post.

Comment: postgres does track changes to tzdata, but if you're seriously using 8.1 as you linked to in your question, that's no longer maintained.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Oh yes, I did missed `Asia/Kolkata` there.
@araqnid: I am using 9.1, but I couldn't find the relevant documentation for 9.1, so posted 8.1's instead.

Comment: @user1144616: I fixed the link. [More about PostgreSQL documentation versioning here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108714/169168).