# Postgres datetime field fetched without timezone in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timezone

datetime is stored in postgres DB with UTC. I could see that the date is 2013-09-28 00:15:52.62504+05:30 in postgres table.

But when I fetch the value via django model, I get the  same datetime field as datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 27, 18, 45, 52, 625040, tzinfo=).

USE_TZ is True and TIME_ZONE is 'Asia/Kolkata' in settings.py file. I think saving to DB works fine as DB contains datetime with correct UTC of +5:30.

What am i doing wrong here?

Please help.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: I can't quite follow the problem. 2013-09-27 18:45 +05:30 is indeed 2013-09-28 00:15.

Comment: Postgres does not understand `Indian Standard Time`. you need to do some custom settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815412/set-custom-timezone-in-django-postgresql-indian-standard-time

Comment: What data type is the field in Postgres?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, yes the value in table is correct, but when I fetch the value via django models it gets converted to UCT+0:00 thus giving value for the model field as datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 27, 18, 45, 52, 625040, tzinfo=). I am not sure why this conversion is done as in django settings I have timezone setup properly.

Comment: @karthikr, I think posgtres already stores the correct value with timezone, but django model converts it back to America timezone, which I do not understand why.

Comment: @Matt, The field is defined as "date_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL"

Comment: The issue has been solved. The problem was that I was using another naive datetime field for calculation of difference in time, whereas the DB field was an aware field. I then converted the naive to timezone aware date, which solved the issue. Thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been solved. The problem was that I was using another naive datetime field for calculation of difference in time, whereas the DB field was an aware field. I then converted the naive to timezone aware date, which solved the issue.

Just in case some one needs to know.