# Set timestamp column's timezone in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I have a trigger on a PostgreSQL table that updates a timestamp field, but I want to get it in the right timezone.  How can I set my column to always be in 'PST' by default? Here is my trigger:

```
ALTER TABLE coastal ADD latest_report TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE coastal ALTER COLUMN latest_report 
SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

UPDATE coastal SET latest_report=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coastal_latest_report()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
BEGIN
   NEW.latest_report = NOW();
   RETURN NEW;
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER coastal_latest_report_modtime BEFORE UPDATE
  ON coastal FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  coastal_latest_report();
```

Comment: Maybe: `new.latest_report := current_timestamp at time zone 'PST';`. Note that using `=` for assignment in PL/pgSQL is deprecated (actually even undocumented). You should use `:=` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Got error: "syntax error at or near 'PST'"

Comment: Aside: never quote the language name `plpgsql`. It's an identifier.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30ab7/1 You probably didn't adjust the code to deal with the single quotes embedded in single quotes. You should get used to using "dollar quoting" for function bodies.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran it again with the correct dollar quoting and I still get the time 7 hours ahead of PST.

Answer (score 9):

> How can I set my column to always be in 'PST' by default?

This is not possible / a misunderstanding. A timestamp column is not in *any* time zone. The time zone is never saved, not even for `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`), which always saves UTC time. That *name* is a tad bit misleading, I'll give you that.

You have two very simple options:

- Save `now()` to a `timestamptz` column.
- Save `now()` to a `timestamp` column. (The time zone offset is *truncated* in the cast.)

If you want timestamps to be ***displayed*** for the 'PST' time zone, set the time zone setting of your session to that time zone (if it is not set already). For instance:

```
SET timezone='America/Anchorage'
```

Ample details in this related answer:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

To find your time zone name:

- [Set custom timezone in Django/PostgreSQL (Indian Standard Time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815412/set-custom-timezone-in-django-postgresql-indian-standard-time/9815951#9815951)

If you want to save the original time zone of input values:

- [Preserve timezone in PostgreSQL timestamptz type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274925/preserve-timezone-in-postgresql-timestamptz-type/20275948#20275948)

Comment: I ran the SET timezone='America/Anchorage' and got a syntax error at or near the '='.

Comment: Maybe I cannot set the timezone of the session in CartoDB, although it runs off of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @cbunn: You did not mention CartoDB. I don't know it, but there should be a way to set the time zone *somehow*.