# Why doesn't the timezone changes in these SQL expressions?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to update the timezone in a certain field of one of my tables. I have tried in several ways seen in some SO posts, but nothing seems to change the actual timezone value.

Anyone can explain why ...

```
select 
    now(), 
    extract(timezone from now()) * interval '1sec', 
    (now()::timestamp || 'PST8PDT')::timestamptz, 
    extract(timezone from (now()::timestamp || 'PST8PDT')::timestamptz) * interval '1sec'
```

All of these fields have the same timezone? The results to me in Fortaleza/Brazil are:

```
2018-10-29 14:52:04.55495-03 | -03:00:00 | 2018-10-29 18:52:04.55495-03 | -03:00:00"
```

Why? Shouldn't the last 2 values have PST timezone?

How can I actually change the timezone for a `timestamp with time zone` field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql

Comment: Don't use `PST8PDT`.  Use a locality based identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles` for US Pacific time.  For your time zone, use `America/Fotraleza`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the time zone because the data type `timestamp with time zone` does not actually store the time zone to begin with. The time zone only serves as input / output modifier. Internally, the respective UTC timestamp value is stored.

The `timezone` setting of the current session determines the *display* of the value. To change the display, change the `timezone` setting. (I.e. pretend to be in a different time zone, where the current time is displayed differently.)

Example:

```
SET timezone = 'PST8PDT';
```

Then retry your test.

The [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct might also be instrumental.

Related:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-data-type-timestamp-with-time-zone/28876266#28876266)
- [Set timestamp column's timezone in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436402/set-timestamp-columns-timezone-in-postgresql/25437229#25437229)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)